# Menu Items not shown After Integrating Butterknife

Tags: android-studio, android-drawable, android-toolbar, android-menu, butterknife

In my current Android project I am using Butterknife library to bind views and use onClick annotations for them. This all works great even in fragments but now I'm at the point where I can't find a solution:Problem was not seen before Integrating ButterKnife. Now menu item and application name disappea after using Butterknife in my application.I am new to androidButterKnife.Anyone can suggest me how to handle this? Thanks in Advance.

```
    package com.example.niroj.firstscreen;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import butterknife.BindColor;
    import butterknife.BindView;
    import butterknife.ButterKnife;
    import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    @BindView(R.id.search)
    MenuItem searchitem;


    @BindView(R.id.fab1)
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

   @BindColor(R.color.colorFolatingButton)
   int Floating_Button_Color;

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.fab1)
    public void  newForm (View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Confirm");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BuilderPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }



    // display menu incons from menu_main XML
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.frontscreen, menu);
        MenuItem  searchitem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchitem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my Menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="hint_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_magnify"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was solved using

//Compile this in projectGradle

```
  classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

//And in appGradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

It might be a silly mistake but i'm glad that i solved it.